# Check if all items in a list are set to the same boolean value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which is populated by a random number of `GameObj` instances each time the program is run.

If an object makes contact with another object in the ArrayList, it will set a boolean called `visible` from `true` to `false`.

Is there a way to check if all of the item instances in the ArrayList have been set to `false` through:

```
XXXX.visible = false
```

Once I can check if they are all set to `false`.

Comment: `list.stream().allMatch`

Comment: `bool allBricks = true; for(GameObj brick : yourList) { if(brick.visible) { allBricks = false; break; } } if(allBricks) { System.out.println("Well Done, Game over."); }`

Comment: In scenarios such as this, another approach is to have a counter, such as `int bricksHits`, that is incremented when a brick is hit. Then you can use a simple if statement, such as `if(bricksHit >= totalBricks) { ... }`, which is only checked once rather than looping over an entire list (in the worst case).

Comment: Yes, let's throw the functional programming solution at the guy new to `Boolean` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.noneMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to do this:

```
if (bricks.stream().noneMatch(GameObj::isVisible)) {
    doStuffIfAllBricksAreInvisible();
}
```

This returns true, if all bricks are invisible.

Additionally I would recommend to take a look at [`Stream.allMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), which returns true, if all elements of the list match the given predicate.

Using `allMatch()` this would look like this:

```
if (bricks.stream().allMatch(b -> !b.isVisible())) {
    doStuffIfAllBricksAreInvisible();
}
```

To complete this, you also can take a look at [`Stream.anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), which returns true, if one of the elements matches the given predicate.

Comment: @HBU You have to adjust this part to fit your needs with your GameObj. Can you please add this to your question? I also updated my post.

Comment: Don't use public fields, better create a getter for it. Alternatively you can use `b -> b.visible` instead of the method reference.

Comment: That's dogmatic Java, but it doesn't make sense. If you have something that needs to be public, axe the boilerplate code and make it public. The argument that the abstraction is worthwhile since you can change the implementation of `getIsVisible` never actually happens. The only place I'd use that boilerplate code is when interfacing with a library whose behavior works through those methods such as Hibernate. The worst are POJOs, the epitome of memorizing a solution and misapplying it instead of writing clean code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java <8, one way will be to store the arraylist size on intialisation in a variable( say variable name be count).

On change of flag from true to false, decrease the count by 1. If flag is already false, do nothing. Now you can just check the count is 0 or not.

If count is 0, print "Well done, Game over" or else continue the game.

For Java 8 or up, you can go for streams API as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Just be cautious about a solution like this as each instance is changing the same variable, and a thread-safe solution is most likely needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use anyMatch because allMatch method returns true when the list is empty

```
if (!bricks.stream().anyMatch(GameObj::isVisible)) {
    // TODO when visible balls not found (all are invisible)
}
```

Comment: While you make a good point, it's going to come down to what his use case, speed needs, and design are. For example, he might want an empty `List` to return `true` or `false`, or it might be guaranteed never to be empty. As for speed, which often comes into play in game design, a simple for loop with a `break` is much faster than the functional solution. Java's functional interface is notoriously much slower than looping alternatives when dealing with a small `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `List` of `boolean` values are all `true` or one value at least is `false`

```
        List<Boolean> booleans = new ArrayList<>();
            
        booleans.add(false);
        booleans.add(true);
        booleans.add(true);
        booleans.add(true);
            
        boolean areAllTrue = booleans.stream().allMatch(Boolean::booleanValue);
        // equivalent to:
        boolean areAllTrue = booleans.stream().allMatch(b -> b);
```

**Important note:** If `booleans.size()` is zero; the result of `allMatch()` is always `true`. So you have to check the size first, or depending on your context needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Java, you probably want to use a for loop like this:

```
bool allFalse = true;
for(int index = 0; index < arrayList.size(); ++index)
    if(arrayList[index].visible) {
        allFalse = false;
        break;
    }
```

`break;` terminates the for loop as soon as you find the first true value since you no longer need to check anymore.

That will work if you know `arrayList` isn't empty, but it might make sense to have `allFalse` be false for an empty `List` since something that isn't there is neither true nor false.

For checking something in an `ArrayList` with not too many elements, a for loop with a `break` will also be significantly faster than a `Stream`. While that might not matter in general where readability and maintainability are paramount, it often does matter in games, especially if he does this check frequently. However, it depends on his use case. Speed may not be important.